# Writing the fourth kinematic formula ($v^2 = v_0^2 + 2a \Delta x$) in a different form

Tags: kinematics

I have noticed that if we play with the formula a bit, we get

\begin{align}
v^2 &= v_0^2 + 2a \Delta x \\
\frac{(v+v_0)}{2} \cdot (v-v_0) &= a \Delta x \\
 \overline{v} \cdot \Delta v &= a \Delta x
\end{align}

Meaning the average velocity $\overline{v}$ times the change in velocity $ \Delta v $ is equal to the (constant) acceleration times the change in place

Is this correct? If so, is there a "physical meaning" behind this form of the formula? Meaning, why does multiplying the average velocity with the difference yields acceleration times displacement?

Comment: "*why does multiplying the average velocity with the difference yields acceleration times displacement?*" You have shown why in your post

Comment: Why was this closed as "homework-like"?  It gives an interesting result and asks whether it has a nice physical interpretation.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert FWIW, my vote was not for the homework reason. Although I can see the take of "check my work" given the explicit "is this correct?" (Many people often see "homework" and overlook the latter part of the closure reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is valid and has a geometric and a physical interpretation.

The hand side corresponds to the kinetic energy of a unit mass, and the right-hand side the work done by a force on the same unit mass. Multiply both sides with $m$ the mass and get

$$ m\, \overline{v}\, \Delta v = m a\,\Delta x \tag{1}$$

Use $F=m a$ and the definition of work $W = F\,\Delta x$ to get

$$ W = m\, \overline{v}\, \Delta v \tag{2}$$

but you can show that the RHS is the change in kinetic energy as

$$ W = m \frac{(v+v_0)}{2} \cdot (v-v_0) = \tfrac{1}{2} m v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} m v_0^2 = \Delta E \tag{3} $$

which goes down to the fundamental principle of work = change in energy.

But there is a geometric interpretation also.

Take the velocity plot vs. time, which under constant acceleration, it is a straight line between $v_0$ and $v$

[image: fig1]

The area under the curve is the distance traveled. From the triangle area formula that is

$$ \Delta x  = \tfrac{1}{2} \Delta t ( v-v_0) \tag{4} $$

but the distance traveled can also be found by the average speed $\overline{v} = \tfrac{v_0+v}{2}$ which you can see above as the area under the rectangle defined by the dashed line.

$$ \Delta x  = \overline{v}\, \Delta t  \tag{5} $$

Combine this with the kinematic equation $\Delta v = a \, \Delta t$ which is solve for time $\Delta t = \tfrac{\Delta v}{a}$ to get

$$ \Delta x  = \overline{v}\, \tfrac{\Delta v}{a}  \tag{6} $$

or

$$ a \Delta x  = \overline{v}\, \Delta v \tag{7} $$

Note that if/when you learn calculus, you will deal with infinitesimal changes and the equation $a\, {\rm d}x = v\, {\rm d}v$ is solve by integration (summation of all the small parts) as

$$\int a\, {\rm d}x =\int v\, {\rm d}v =\tfrac{1}{2} v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} v_0^2 \tag{8}$$

which is the solution for non-constant $a$ and matches with equation (3) above as it is interpreted as work = change in kinetic energy.

An example is when you have a spring with $F=-k x$ and thus $ a =-\tfrac{1}{m} k x$, you use it in (8) to get

$$- \int \tfrac{1}{m} k x\,{\rm x} = -\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{k}{m} x^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2} v_0^2$$

which is equivalent to the energy balance between the potential energy of the spring and the kinetic energy of the mass at initial conditions (rhs) and at current conditions (lhs).

$$ \tfrac{1}{2} k x^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} m v^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} m v_0^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

The average acceleration is defined as $\bar{a} = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$, and the average velocity is $\bar{v} = \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$.  For a constant acceleration $a = \bar{a}$, so the right hand side of your expression could be rewritten:
$$ a\, \Delta x = \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} \Delta x = \Delta v \, \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \Delta v\, \bar{v}.$$

This shows that your expression is correct, but I can't find any deep physical significance in it.

Answer (score 0):

Average velocity by basic definition is the average distance covered by an object divided by the average time required to do so.

Hence, v avg = s/t

Also, acceleration is the rate of change of velocity, or simply change in velocity divided by the time interval.

Hence, the LHS is the displacement of the body times its acceleration